# add target blank attr programmatically failed

Tags: jquery, css

how to add target blank to a  programmatically using jquery? I tried

```
$('#target a').attr('target="_blank"');
```

but nothing happen? I'm sure my selector work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually misusing the syntax of `.attr(attriute,value)`

Try,

```
$('#target a').attr("target","_blank");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2xj6rLhw/)

Answer (score 0):

I thing you missed syntax.

[refer this example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_attr_set)

you have to write like:

```
$('#target a').attr("target","_blank");
```